# Updating values in a json sting

Tags: python, json

This is the string I am looking to update.

```
Koordinatstring = 
    {
            "Koords":"Koordinates",
            "TrueCoords":
            {
                    "FirstFind":
                    {
                            "X":"134",
                            "Y":"223",
                    },
                    "SecondFind":
                    {
                            "X":"721",
                            "Y":"632",
                    },
                    "ThirdFind":
                    {
                            "X":"412",
                            "Y":"344",
                    },
                    "FourthFind":
                    {
                            "X":"612",
                            "Y":"532",
                    }
            }
    }
```

I know how to extract only the X or Y value from FourthFind for example. But what I am looking to do at the moment, is to access that value and replace it with a new one that I want to input.

I would like to do something simliar to:

```
k = json.dumps(koordinatstring)
l = json.loads(k)

Kords1 = l['TrueCoords']['FirstFind']['X']
```

To overwrite data, but I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: It's *just a dictionary*. You can assign to keys in dictionaries, yes. `l['TrueCoords']['FourthFind']` is the dictionary, `l['TrueCoords']['FourthFind']['X'] = '42'` updates the value for the `'X'` key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the data may have come from a JSON document, once parsed you have ordinary dictionaries referencing other ordinary dictionaries.

You can always assign to a key in a dictionary:

```
 d = {'foo': 'bar'}
 d['foo'] = 'spam'
```

You just have a nested dictionary, so you need to string together a few `[...]` subscriptions to access the one you want to change:

```
l['TrueCoords']['FourthFind']['X'] = '42'
```

This sets the `'X'` key to the new value `'42'`, in the dictionary referenced by `l['TrueCoords']['FourthFind']`.

Comment: Thank you, helped me! Will keep it in mind for the future. :)